# How get parameters from response after POST request?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have one simple controller for example

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public class HelloController {
        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
...
     model.addAttribute("startDate", startDate);
     model.addAttribute("endDate", endDate);
     model.addAttribute("msisdn", msisdn);
            return "hello";
        }
```

And ome JSP page with simple form with POST request

```
<form action="http://1.....:8887/getCallDetailGeneral" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="startDate" value="${startDate}"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="endDate" value="${endDate}"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="msisdn" value="${msisdn}"/>
    <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

When I press `send` button I send POST request and get some response.

I not understand how can I get parameters from this response? or error to my code.

Fro example this response return me JSON string. How can I pass it to my java code(new or this controller)

Comment: Show the controller that will receive the `POST` request.

Comment: I have ONE controller with FORM. And I send POST FORM to url int action in this form. I have not another controller. This url redirect me to some page(not my page) and I vant get response frome this page to my server controller(in i need create this new controller then how do it?)

Comment: The `<form>` will `POST` its contents to the URL at the `action` attribute. In that form, this URL is `/getCallDetailGeneral`. So, you have to create a `@RequestMapping`-annotated method in a controller to answer for POST requests in that URL.

Comment: Can do you write a simple code how do it?

Comment: See [Create Web Controller](https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/#initial), there is a method handling a `POST` in this example.

Comment: I wrote that the reference to that redirects form is not mine. This page is not on my server. it outside.

Comment: Are you saying you don't control what is at URL `http://1.....:8887/getCallDetailGeneral`? If so, you have to change that URL. If, on the other hand, what you mean is you don't own the page with that form but you do control what is at `http://1.....:8887/`, then create a controller to answer at that form's URL, like `@RequestMapping(value="/getCallDetailGeneral", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String myMethodThatWillHandleTheForm(...`.

Comment: There is some page. for example page1 by address 1.2.3.4:1234/page1 and this page has 2 parameters p1 = "p1" and p2 = "p2". I have my pages for example myPage with form with 2 parameters. I write this parameters in my form  and send to 1.2.3.4:1234/page1 and I wait until page1 return me some data. I want get this data in my code. And 1.2.3.4:1234/page1 - contains on computer my grandmother for exapmle. I know what parameters I need pass to this page and I want get result to my page from this page

Comment: @user5620472 you have to add information to your question, that you try to receive response from **remote** server but not from your controller

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you submit POST request to getCallDetailGeneral and need to read response which is JSON.
If you are using jquery, you can POST to getCallDetailGeneral and read the json response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[The Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/index.html)** or **[jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)** library to interact with remote server.

Solution with **Apache HttpComponents** library:

1. Add ***dependency*** to your `pom.xml`:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
       <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
       <version>4.5.1</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Form:

   ```
   <form action="/" method="post">
       <input type="text" name="startDate"/>
       <input type="text" name="endDate"/>
       <input type="text" name="msisdn"/>
       <input type="submit"/>
   </form>
   ```
3. Make controller, that ***show form*** via `GET` method:

   ```
   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String indexController(){
       return "index";
   }
   ```
4. Make controller (`Rest.java`) than ***receive parameters*** from form via `POST` method and ***pass them to remote server***:

   ```
   import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
   import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
   import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
   import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
   import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
   import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
   import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
   import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
   import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
   import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
   import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.List;

   @RestController
   public class Rest {
       @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
       public String getData(@RequestParam(value="startDate") String startDate,
                             @RequestParam(value="endDate") String endDate,
                             @RequestParam(value="msisdn") String msisdn) throws IOException {

           String result = "";
           CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
           try {
               HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080");

               List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<>();
               urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("startDate", startDate));
               urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("endDate", endDate));
               urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("msisdn", msisdn));
               HttpEntity postParams = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters);
               httpPost.setEntity(postParams);

               result += "Executing request " + httpPost.getRequestLine() + "\n";

               //Create a custom response handler
               ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new ResponseHandler<String>() {

                   @Override
                   public String handleResponse(
                           final HttpResponse response) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
                       int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                       if (status >= 200 && status < 300) {
                           HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                           return entity != null ? EntityUtils.toString(entity) : null;
                       } else {
                           throw new ClientProtocolException("Unexpected response status: " + status);
                       }
                   }

               };
               String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);
               result += responseBody;
           } finally {
               httpclient.close();
           }

           return result;
       }
   }
   ```
5. Replace `http://localhost:8080` with your remote server's address;
6. You can get response from remote server with this code:

   ```
   String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);
   result += responseBody;
   ```

---

Solution with **jsoup** library:

1. Add ***dependency*** to your `pom.xml`:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
       <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
       <version>1.8.3</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Make controller (`Rest.java`) than ***receive parameters*** from form via `POST` method and ***pass them to remote server***:

   ```
   import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

   import java.io.IOException;

   @RestController
   public class Rest {
       @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
       public String getData(@RequestParam(value="startDate") String startDate,
                             @RequestParam(value="endDate") String endDate,
                             @RequestParam(value="msisdn") String msisdn) throws IOException {

           return Jsoup.connect("http://localhost:8080")
                   .data("startDate", startDate)
                   .data("endDate", endDate)
                   .data("msisdn", msisdn)
                   .post()
                   .toString();
       }
   }
   ```